# How do I remove unneccessary boot device options?

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, partitioning, grub

Long story short: had win8, decided to make dualboot, installed manjaro linux (mounted /boot/efi to windows' efi partition), oh noes grub doesnt show option to log into win8, managed to create win8 option via grub-customizer, logged into win8, decided to remove manjaro, created recovery usb via win8, used [this](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/) guide, deleted manjaro partitions, oh noes there were unneccessary boot options, mounted efi partition in win8 and deleted manjaro, gummiboot folders and grub.cfg hoping that they'd dissapear. They didn't.

[image]

So how to remove these unneccessary options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These entries are stored in UEFI’s NVRAM. You could use [`efibootmgr`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr) on Linux (has to be UEFI-booted) to remove/manage them. This program should be available (either installed by default or from the repositories) on all recent Linux distributions.

Run `efibootmgr` as `root` to get a list of boot entries:

```
[root@db-nb-11 ~]# efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0019
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0019,000C,000A,0006,0007,0008,0009,000B,000E,000F,0010,0011,0012,0013,000D
Boot0000  Setup
Boot0001  Boot Menu
Boot0002  Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0003  Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0004  ME Configuration Menu
Boot0005  Rescue and Recovery
Boot0006* USB CD
Boot0007* USB FDD
Boot0008  ATAPI CD0
Boot0009  ATA HDD2
Boot000A* ATA HDD0
Boot000B  ATA HDD1
Boot000C* USB HDD
Boot000D* PCI LAN
Boot000E  ATAPI CD1
Boot000F  ATAPI CD2
Boot0010  Other CD
Boot0011  ATA HDD3
Boot0012  ATA HDD4
Boot0013  Other HDD
Boot0014* IDER BOOT CDROM
Boot0015* IDER BOOT Floppy
Boot0016* ATA HDD
Boot0017* ATAPI CD:
Boot0018* PCI LAN
Boot0019* Arch Linux
```

You might notice that most of these entries aren’t relevant to you. Better take care not to delete anything important, who knows what might happen. ;)

To delete entry `Boot0019`, you’d have to execute the following command:

```
bootmgr --bootnum 19 --delete-bootnum
```

Or, if you like short options:

```
bootmgr -b 19 -B
```

Comment: In-depth guide would be nice

Comment: Well, here you go, @foxneZz.

Comment: when I install grub, do I have option to boot windows via boot device selection menu or only through grub? I just forgot to look when I had manjaro. If I fk up my system I would need to find another windows 8 computer or try recovering through liveusb which can be troublesome. Always having option to boot windows through boot menu makes experimenting with linux much easier. I plan to install Arch linux btw :) @Daniel

Comment: Why don't you just use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html)  If you don't have an Windows 8.1 installation disk go ahead and download one from Microsoft using the tool.

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi) is the source material for this answer

Comment: I have Win8 iso. But I only have one flash drive. EasyUEFI seems to be exactly what I've been looking for.