# Can a PC show more ways to boot than actually exist?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, efi

I was running Windows 10 along with a small partition for Ubuntu on my [Acer Aspire (V Nitro) VN7-592G](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6403?b=1) with a Crucial SSD and a Toshiba HDD.

I didn't use this partition and erased it some time ago, I had still the option to boot to ''ubuntu'' in the F12 menu of my pc.

Today I installed Manjaro on the whole drive, creating a new partition table and all first, but the Ubuntu option is still there.

I even tried deleting it following [How do I remove unneccessary boot device options?](https://superuser.com/questions/887458/how-do-i-remove-unnecessary-boot-device-options) but it still shows.

How is that possible and how can I delete it?

Comment: If I get this correctly, you are trying to clean your hard drive completely? If yes, the simplest way is to use Diskpart. Do you have only a single drive?

Comment: I have 2, I disconnected the second and the ubuntu tag shows, I swapped the drives with a blank one (no operating system installed on this second drive) and this tag still shows (even though ubuntu has never touched this drive).

Comment: Try using bootice: https://bootice.en.lo4d.com/windows This means reinstallation w10 though.

Comment: What do you see with `sudo efibootmgr`?

Comment: when I execute sudo efibootmgr a list with the manjaro installation, ubuntu ¿?, and cd and usb boot options.

When I delete it and run the command again it doesn't show until I restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

For example, I just installed CentOS 8 on a server using UEFI partitioning, then reformatted the drive to erase the OS. Despite that, that machine's boot menu still shows CentOS 8 .

The method to delete it depends on the BIOS options of your PC, which are accessed by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> during or shortly after the Power On Self Test ('POST'). Page 38 of your manual (linked in your question) suggests you *select Boot from the categories listed on the left of the screen*. Try deleting excess items from the list of OS to boot from listed there.